# XmlPullParser require issue when parsing xml data on Android

Tags: android, xml

I'm following the android xml parsing tutorial (http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html#analyze), however when stepping through it, it seems to fail at:

```
parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "rss");
```

and then ends up dropping to the finally clause. Just wondering if anyone could spot what the issue could be as I've played around with it for hours without much success.

The feed I am trying to read is: http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml

Any help is greatly appreciated, please find the code below:

```
package com.proxama.news_bbc;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.channels.Channels;
import java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.Xml;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.provider.DocumentsContract.Document;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private static final String ns = null;
    /*
     * Only interested in the content of the following XML tags for each news
     * item:
     * 
     * item/media:thumbnail item/pubDate item/link item/description item/title
     */
    private void skip(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException,
            IOException {
        if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
        int depth = 1;
        while (depth != 0) {
            switch (parser.next()) {
                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    depth--;
                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    depth++;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static class Entry {
        public final String title;
        public final String link;
        public final String summary;

        private Entry(String title, String summary, String link) {
            this.title = title;
            this.summary = summary;
            this.link = link;
        }
    }

    // Parses the contents of an entry. If it encounters a title, summary, or
    // link tag, hands them off
    // to their respective "read" methods for processing. Otherwise, skips the
    // tag.


    // Processes title tags in the feed.
    private String readTitle(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException,
            XmlPullParserException {
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "title");
        String title = readText(parser);
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, ns, "title");
        return title;
    }

    // Processes link tags in the feed.
    private String readLink(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException,
            XmlPullParserException {
        String link = "";
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "link");
        String tag = parser.getName();
        String relType = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "rel");
        if (tag.equals("link")) {
            if (relType.equals("alternate")) {
                link = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "href");
                parser.nextTag();
            }
        }
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, ns, "link");
        return link;
    }

    // Processes summary tags in the feed.
    private String readSummary(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException,
            XmlPullParserException {
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "summary");
        String summary = readText(parser);
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, ns, "summary");
        return summary;
    }

    // For the tags title and summary, extracts their text values.
    private String readText(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException,
            XmlPullParserException {
        String result = "";
        if (parser.next() == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
            result = parser.getText();
            parser.nextTag();
        }
        return result;
    }

    private Entry readEntry(XmlPullParser parser)
            throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "item");
        String title = null;
        String summary = null;
        String link = null;
        while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
            if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                continue;
            }
            String name = parser.getName();
            if (name.equals("title")) {
                title = readTitle(parser);
            } else if (name.equals("summary")) {
                summary = readSummary(parser);
            } else if (name.equals("link")) {
                link = readLink(parser);
            } else {
                skip(parser);
            }
        }
        return new Entry(title, summary, link);
    }

    private List readFeed(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException,
            IOException {
        List entries = new ArrayList();
        String xmlContents = parser.toString();
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "rss");
        Log.d("className", "Up to here ");
        while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
            if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                continue;
            }
            String name = parser.getName();
            // Starts by looking for the news item tag
            if (name.equals("item")) {
                entries.add(readEntry(parser));
            } else {
                skip(parser);
            }
        }
        return entries;
    }

    private List parseXml(InputStream in) throws XmlPullParserException,
            IOException {

        try {
            XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();
            parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
            parser.setInput(in, null);
            return readFeed(parser);
        } finally {
            in.close();
        }
    }

    private String downloadUrl(String myurl) throws IOException {
        // TODO allow for internal storage if external is unavailable or full
        File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        String Directory = root.getAbsolutePath() + "/xmls";
        String xmlFileName = "bbc_news_rss.xml";
        String fullXmlPath = Directory + "/" + xmlFileName;

        File dir = new File(Directory);
        if (dir.exists() == false) {
            dir.mkdirs();
        }

            /*URL url = new URL(myurl);
            InputStream is = url.openStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(fullXmlPath);

            byte[] b = new byte[2048];
            int length;

            while ((length = is.read(b)) != -1) {
                os.write(b, 0, length);
            }

            is.close();
            os.close();*/
        URL url = new URL(myurl);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        // Starts the query
        conn.connect();
        InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();

        Log.d("className", "Saved XML file to: " + fullXmlPath);
        Log.d("className", "Starting to parse XML file: " + fullXmlPath);
        //InputStream in = new FileInputStream(fullXmlPath);
        try {
            parseXml(in);
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return fullXmlPath;
    }

    // Uses AsyncTask to create a task away from the main UI thread. This task
    // takes a
    // URL string and uses it to create an HttpUrlConnection. Once the
    // connection
    // has been established, the AsyncTask downloads the contents of the webpage
    // as
    // an InputStream. Finally, the InputStream is converted into a string,
    // which is
    // displayed in the UI by the AsyncTask's onPostExecute method.
    private class DownloadWebpageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... stringUrl) {
            try {
                Log.d("className", "Downloading url: " + stringUrl[0]);
                return downloadUrl(stringUrl[0]);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return "Unable to retrieve file.";
            }
        }

        // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Log.d("className",
                    "In onpostexecute and result of downloadUrl is: " + result);

            // If the file has been saved correctly, parse it.
            if (result != "Unable to retrieve file.") {
                Log.d("className", "Creating list view");
                createList();
            }

        }
    }

    /** Pull in the XML from http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml */
    public void pull_xml(View view) {
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            // can connect so fetch XML file
            Log.d("className", "Successfully connected to network!");
            new DownloadWebpageTask()
                    .execute("http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml");
        } else {
            // display error
            Log.d("className",
                    "Unable to connect to network, trying to use a previously saved local xml file");
        }

    }

    public void createList() {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Get ListView object from XML
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        // Defined Array values to show in ListView
        String[] values = new String[] { "Ukraine begins 'anti-terror' action" };

        // Define a new Adapter
        // First parameter - Context
        // Second parameter - Layout for the row
        // Third parameter - ID of the TextView to which the data is written
        // Forth - the Array of data

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);

        // Assign adapter to ListView
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    // Original classes and methods that came by default with new android
    // projects.
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // retrieve the XML and create list view
        pull_xml(null);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What `finally` clause do you mean? Where you call your `parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "rss");` method there is none. Does is throw an exception, and if yes which one?

Comment: It's the `finally` in `parseXml`, after stepping past `parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "rss");` is drops straight in to that finally.

Comment: So some exception is thrown in the line where you call `parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "rss");`. Can you see which one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has several mistakes:

`DownloadWebpageTask.onPostExecute`: here you are trying to compare `Strings` with `!=` operator. It's wrong, you'll always get `false`. The correct way is to use `equals` method:

```
if ("Unable to retrieve file.".equals(result)) {
    Log.d("className", "Creating list view");
    createList();
}
```

`createList()` method: what's the purpose of calling `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` here if you already did it at the `onCreate`?

`pull_xml(View view)` method: what's the purpose of `view` argument? You are not using it at this method.

`parseXml` method: please add `parser.nextTag()`

Comment: I made your suggested changes and that appeared to fix the issue and it is now stepping over `parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "rss");`. I suppose it would have been due to the lack of the `parser.nextTag()`? I'm not sure, I'll have to investigate further. Thanks nikis!